# QField cloud: can't save layer, could not convert value for attribute to type Integer64

Tags: qfield, cloud-gis

I have a problem regarding QField cloud. I have a project with a layer which I want to create new objects within. If I import the project via cloud, the added objects can't be saved, it shows:

QField Layer "xyz" kann nicht mit dem neu erzeugten Feature -2 gespeichert werden. Grund: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
Provider errors: [image: Could not convert value for attribute "fid" to type Integer64]
2024-01-09 13:58:02:365
OGR Unbalanced call to leaveUpdateMode() w.r.t. enterUpdateMode()
2024-01-09 13:58:02:361
QField Änderungen konnten nicht gespeichert werden, Rollback.
2024-01-09 13:58:02:360
Commit errors:
ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

If i copy the same project from the pc to the smartphone and import it as a local project, it works normally.

Perhaps someone knows what I'm missing? I'm not that experienced with QGIS and QField yet.